# Star topology in Unison with selective bidirectional syncs?

Tags: synchronization, unison

Let's say I have a server where I'd like to keep my central Unison repository, and I have two machines with directories `Documents` and `.config` on each. I'd like to synchronise `Documents` and `.config` to server but only `Documents` should be synchronised between both client machines. So there should be three directories on the server,
`Documents`, `.config_machine1`, `.config_machine2`, where `Documents` is common between the two client machines, and each `.config` is specific two each client machine. Is this possible with unison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run two different Unison profiles on each machine. So on your server, you would have your files look something like

```
Unison
 \_Common
 |  \_Documents
 \_Machine1
 |  \_.config
 \_Machine2
    \_.config
```

and then on each machine you would have two different [Unison profiles](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#profile), `common.prf` to sync the Documents folder, and `specific.prf` to sync that machine's `.config` folder.

Comment: Is it possible and safe to use two profiles using fsmonitor at the same time?
Do I need to run two separate program instances?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking you'd run two separate instances. Something like `unison -repeat watch common; unison -repeat watch specific`. This should create two different instances of fsmonitor, and that should be fine since there is no overlap between the files they are each monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

### This solution feels like a bad idea. At the very least, there must be a cleaner way to execute this idea, but I'm not sure what it is.

---

You could do a cute thing with symbolic links on your two machines. You could have the files on your server look like this,

```
Unison
 \_Documents
 \_.config_machine1
 \_.config_machine2
```

and then on each of your client machines, you could rename the `.config` folder to `.config_machine1` and create a symbolic link named `.config` to `.config_machine1`.

```
cp /path/to/the/dotconfig/folder
mv .config .config_machine1
cd /tmp
ln -sd /full/path/to/.config_machine1 
mv .config_machine1 /path/to/the/dotconfig/folder/.config
```

Then you have each machine sync its `Documents` folder, and its own `.config_machine${i}` folder. And with the symbolic links, when a program on your machine goes to look for its settings in the `.config` folder, it'll be linked to `.config_machine${i}`.